# Core reading resources for Java Multithreading / Concurrency?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

[The Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/further.html) listed a couple of books for further reading regarding threading / concurrency:

1. [Concurrent Programming in Java: Design Principles and Pattern](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310090)
2. [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)
3. [Concurrency: State Models & Java Programs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470093552)

(Since going through a book could take a hundred hours,) Out of these three books, which would be the most comprehensive one?

Comment: `Java Concurrency in Practice `

Comment: Similar post:[Books on threads and concurrency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495395/books-on-threads-and-concurrency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i propose you something slightly different: [Programming Concurrency on the JVM](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781934356760.do?green=DD990CBC-8AB2-5157-9C3F-61B524D0038B&cmp=af-mybuy-9781934356760.IP).

This will explain to you the different models and the different problems with concurrency on the JVM. Not entirely targeted at Java, but at the JVM ecosystem, it will give you a deep understanding, along with the technical tools.